# How to debug Java code in IDE (Eclipse, Spring Tool Suite) like Visual Studio?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, visual-studio, spring-tool-suite

First of all, I know my question is not a good question, I should say sorry for my this question, but this question confused me for a long time.

.Net/Visual Studio: I am coming from a .Net background. When I develop a project, I and my team are using the Visual Studio. When I debug the server side code (C# class code), **it is very convenient since I use Visual Studio. I set the breakpoint, then I hover my mouse above the code, I can see what is the value of a variable or array values of a variable**, so I can quickly know what is the value of a variable.

Java/Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite: When I was a student, all my courses are using Java with Eclipse, including course assignment and projects, and I found it was not convenient for debugging. Because I need to go to a debug mode, then I need to see **a separate Windows** [image] within Eclipse, **which shows the value of a variable in each row**, this is not very efficient way to debug compared to debug in Visual Studio.

Now, I am going to develop the project using Java. This project is based on Spring framework. Then I found many people are using Spring Tool Suite, so I am going to use this IDE to develop my project.

My question is: Can we debug Java in an IDE like we debug in Visual Studio? What about debug code in Spring framework using Spring Tool Suite? Thanks.

Update:
All right, [image]. I am testing this easy java program in Eclipse. I set the breakpoint, then I click "Run" -> "Debug", then I open a debug perspective. In the past, I only can see what is the value for variable a and b in **Red Circle 2**, but now, look like recently, when I put my mouse on variable a and b in **Red Circle 1**, I can see its value immediately? If yes, when this feature added to Eclipse? I am quite sure we cannot do so in Eclipse in the past.

Comment: Please, show an example of the "same" problem in both languages.

Comment: Coming from Visual Studio, IDEs like Eclipse might seem a bit old school in terms of debugging. Have you tried using IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal I want a free license of IDE for my personal project.

Comment: What does "like we debug in Visual Studio" *mean*? And just what's "old school" about it?

Comment: @QuestionContributor The Community version of IntelliJ Idea is free. I am not sure about the features you require though

Comment: @nitind I believe I have explained clearly in my post. Let me know if you still do not understand after reading my post. Thanks

Comment: If you really just mean showing you the value when you hover over it in the editor showing the source, that's been there for years. You can drag a view, using its title bar, out of the main window to create a new window if you want. Unless I'm mistaken, you otherwise haven't explained what you want it to act/look like instead of how it is by default.

Comment: @nitind  Yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are actually debugging an application, you can hover over a variable in an open editor *for the selected stack frame in the Debug view* and see the variable's value. This is a long available feature.

You can also drag a view, using its title bar, out of the main window to create a new window if you want. I don't think this is heavily used, and may not work correctly with multiple screens, but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing a line based on IDE settings. Most likely, you're running in debug mode in VS even though you don't explicitly say it. That being said, your question is basic; of course, you can debug Java like C#.

Comment: "of course, you can debug Java like C#" How? I attach a image to explain how I debug in Java

Comment: Debugging is debugging. I use many languages and the process is generally the same. I ask that you please provide an example of debugging in VS that you, or anyone,  cannot reproduce in Java?Spring?

Comment: I believe the OP wants the debugging environment to be somewhat similar to VS where you can hover over a variable for its value. Eclipse like he says lists out all the variable and values in a side window which makes it very difficult if u want to view values in lists or other similar objects

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I added one example in my post. Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal Yes, you understand my question well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can debug java code in Eclipse. Set a break point to the line you want to debug and select an object/variable/whichever and inspect it or add to watch.